# "the example below" or "the below example"?

Tags: grammar

I am wondering which one is a proper structure for an academic writing text?

> the example below

or

> the below example

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/609/16833

Comment: I did not see @Em1 's comment because they provided a URL only. Any ways, here's what the OP might want to know from Webster's: **below** *adjective*:  written or discussed lower on the same page or on a following page - **First Known Use of BELOW** 1916

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The example below" is more common, but I don't find "the below example" offensive. If you replace "above" with "below" then both orders are very common.  Still, I recommend "the example below," which sounds a bit more natural.

Comment: One of the reasons why "the example below" is more common is that "below" can be an adverb or a preposition, but not an adjective. (Actually, "the below example" would sound a little off to me, and might alarm my grammar detector.)

Comment: Check this out: [Which is correct: “the below information” or “the information below”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/609/which-is-correct-the-below-information-or-the-information-below)

Answer (score -1):

Below is a preposition or adverb, so neither example is appropriate.  "The following example..." is appropriate.